# Rails 3 - Access Scoping Chain to reuse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to reuse a scope from a AR call.  Here is my example

```
@current_account.items.report_by_month(month, year)
```

Inside the report_my_month scope, I wanted to reuse the @current_account

```
def self.report_by_month(month, year)
    values = Values.where(:current_account => USE SCOPE FROM SELF)
    scope = scoped{}
    scope = scope.where(:values => values)
end
```

This is only sample code to figure out how to do it, because the query is much more complicated as it is a report.  Thanks!

Comment: Please post your model code..

Comment: The model is massive and I'm trying to access the current_account in the self.report_by_month.  Not sure why the rest of the model would even be relevant.  Trying to see if I can get a scope.current_account.subdomain or something like that

Comment: We don't need the entire model code, but posting the relationships between the models will help you get your answer faster.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason that you can't simply pass it as an additional parameter?

```
def self.report_by_month(month, year, current_account)
    values = Values.where(:current_account => current_account)
    scope = scoped{}
    scope = scope.where(:values => values)
end
```

Called with

```
@current_account.items.report_by_month(month, year, @current_account)
```

Edit:

If you're just trying to avoid having to pass @current_account again, I would suggest adding an instance method on your Account class for this.

```
class Account
  has_many :items

  def items_reported_by_month(month, year)
    self.items.report_by_month(month, year, id)
  end
end
```

Which you could then call with

```
@current_account.items_reported_by_month(month, year)
```

Comment: That's the desired effect - I'm curious to know if the context that the scope has been called in is available implicitly. If possible, I want to avoid doing something like `current_user.invoices.overdue_for(current_user)`.

Comment: short answer is that method is scoped on the class so your scope is the class itself not the instance of the class.

Comment: Scopes are essentially class methods that modify a single instance of ActiveRecord::Relation. You're not creating a new instance every time you call a method, so there's no chain to go up. I've updated my answer with a solution that avoids `current_user.invoices.overdue_for(current_user)` type calls.

Comment: I've awarded this answer the bounty because of your comment about scopes modifying an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` - I'm interested in the reason rather than the workaround. Hard to communicate that when running a bounty on someone else's question! Thanks :)